# Join to get the last date with less then or equal

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have 2 tables. the first table is total_payment and the second table is Schedule_down
beginning

total_payment

| ID | payment_date | accumulated_total_payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2020-01-12 | 105 |
| AAA | 2020-01-13 | 110 |
| AAA | 2020-01-14 | 120 |
| AAA | 2020-01-15 | 125 |
| AAA | 2020-01-16 | 125 |
| AAA | 2020-01-17 | 150 |

Schedule_down

| ID | Date_schedule | payment_schedule |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2020-01-11 | 110 |
| AAA | 2020-01-13 | 120 |
| AAA | 2020-01-15 | 130 |
| AAA | 2020-01-16 | 140 |
| AAA | 2020-01-18 | 150 |

how can i join from table total_payment to Schedule_down to get the last Date_schedule based on accumulated_total_payment <= payment_schedule and also by ID ?

my expectation result is

| ID | payment_date | accumulated_total_payment | Date_schedule |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2020-01-12 | 105 | 2020-01-11 |
| AAA | 2020-01-13 | 110 | 2020-01-11 |
| AAA | 2020-01-14 | 120 | 2020-01-14 |
| AAA | 2020-01-15 | 125 | 2020-01-15 |
| AAA | 2020-01-16 | 125 | 2020-01-15 |
| AAA | 2020-01-17 | 150 | 2020-01-18 |

anyone can help ? thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try below approach

```
select any_value(tp).*, min(sd.Date_schedule) Date_schedule
from total_payment tp
join Schedule_down sd
on tp.ID = sd.ID 
and accumulated_total_payment <= payment_schedule
group by to_json_string(tp)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` and `join`:

```
select p.*, sd.Date_schedule
from total_payment p left join
     (select sd.*,
             lead(Date_schedule) over (partition by id order by Date_schedule) as next_Date_schedule
      from schedule_down sd
     ) sd
     on p.id = sd.id and
        p.date >= s.Date_schedule and
        (p.date < s.next_Date_schedule or s.next_Date_schedule is null);
```

Basically, this puts an "end" date on each `schedule_down` row and then uses this for matching.